# Handling multiple socket connections

Tags: java, sockets, break

In the application that I inherited I was told that I had to convert the application from a one port one connection application to a multiple connection application.  I'm still very new to socket programming and could really use some help in tackling this issue.  Unfortunately, there are no other people on my team and I'm still trying to rifle through this code and learn the application.

Here is my code issue.  I have a run() that calls a connect() in the same class but I have to be able to execute the rest of the run() code after EACH connection is made and verify that the activeSocket is still in the activeSockets list.  Currently, the connect() code is setup to get ALL the connections in the maxActiveSockets list BEFORE moving on in the run() but again and that is part of the problem.  I tried to break out of the outerloop after the first connection is made and then I do NOT see the second connection making it to the application.  I could really use a second set of eyes on this.

I hope this makes sense.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Here is the run() code:

```
public void run() {
int cnt;
Socket socket;
started = true;

if (!shouldTerminate) {
    LOGGER.info("Connecting to host " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    connect();
    hardstandin = false;
}
startTimers();
while (!shouldTerminate) {
    // Make sure connection stays up unless shouldTerminate is set
    if (!shouldTerminate) {

        // ***** 20130912 MS - Per Shannon's email this method had to be changed to utilize the activeSocket fields. *****
        Iterator&lt;ActiveSocket&gt; it = activeSockets.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            ActiveSocket activeSocket = it.next();
            socket = activeSocket.getSocket();
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = activeSocket.getDataInputStream();
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = activeSocket.getDataOutputStream();

            // ORIGINAL CODE BLOCK STARTS HERE ==&gt;
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (socket) {
                    try {
                        //LOGGER.info(&quot;Sending notifyAll on socket&quot;);
                        //socket.notifyAll();
                        if (!shouldTerminate) {
                            if (!getNeedReconnect().get()) {
                                hardstandin = false;
                                socket.wait();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
                        LOGGER.info(&quot;Error waiting for new socket Interrupted Exception received.&quot;);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (getNeedReconnect().get()) {
                hardstandin = true;
                final String channelName = &quot;Bank &quot; + bankInit + &quot;; Bank ID &quot; + getBankID();
                final String logMessage = channelName.concat(&quot;\n\nData input stream on socket connection could not be read.  Attempting to re-establish the connection.&quot;);
                final String subject = channelName.concat(&quot; Socket connection error&quot;);
                ATMServer.sendNotification(subject, logMessage);

                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (final IOException ex) {
                    LOGGER.info(ERR_SOCKCLOSE);
                }
                socket = null;
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.warn(&quot;Could not close input/output streams: &quot; + FormatData.formatStack(e));
                }

                dataInputStream = null;
                dataOutputStream = null;
                connect();

                if (((dataInputStream != null) && (dataOutputStream != null)) || shouldTerminate) {
                    getNeedReconnect().set(false);
                    hardstandin = false;
                    synchronized (this) {
                        LOGGER.info(&quot;Sending notifyAll on channel&quot;);
                        this.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            } // &lt;== ORIGINAL CODE BLOCK ENDS HERE.
        }
    }
}

// *** shutdown the process
// need to shutdown the positiveBalance
// need to shut down each receive queuer
synchronized (this) {
    LOGGER.info(&quot;Sending notifyAll on channel&quot;);
    this.notifyAll();
}
// ***** 20130913 MS - Per Shannon's email, modify code to utilize the multiple connection code. *****
Iterator&lt;ActiveSocket&gt; it = activeSockets.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    ActiveSocket activeSocket = it.next();
    socket = activeSocket.getSocket();

    // ORIGINAL CODE BLOCK STARTS HERE. ==&gt;
    if (socket != null) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.info(ERR_SOCKCLOSE);
        }
    }
    // &lt;== ORIGINAL CODE BLOCK ENDS HERE.
}
stopTimers();
terminated = true;
started = false;
if (internalTerminatedSignal != null) {
    try {
        internalTerminatedSignal.await(COUNTDOWN_WAIT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.info(FormatData.fullStackTrace(e));
    }
}
if (terminatedSignal != null) {
    LOGGER.info(this.getClass().getName() + &quot; Updating countdown latch&quot;);
    terminatedSignal.countDown();
}
```

}

Here is the connect() code:

```
public void connect() {

boolean clientSocket = false;

LOGGER.info(&quot;Connecting ... &quot;);

while (!shouldTerminate) {

    ActiveSocket activeSocket = null;
    Socket newSocket = null;
    int tries = 0;
    int loopCounter = 0;

    if (isServer) {
        if (host == null) {
            LOGGER.info(&quot;Must specify a host ip or host name with HOST configuration tag &quot;);
            return;
        } else {
            while (!shouldTerminate && (activeSockets.size() &lt; this.maxActiveSockets)) {
                activeSocket = new ActiveSocket(this);
                newSocket = null;       
                if (serverSocket != null) {                         
                    try {
                        LOGGER.info(&quot;Accept socket.&quot;);
                        newSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    } catch (final IOException ex) {
                        if (shouldTerminate) {
                            if (ex.getMessage() != null) {
                                LOGGER.info(ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        } else {
                            LOGGER.info(&quot;IOException while accepting connection.&quot;);
                            LOGGER.warn(FormatData.fullStackTrace(ex));
                        }
                        newSocket = null;
                    }
                    if (newSocket != null) {
                        try {
                            LOGGER.info(&quot;Server socket keepalive ... &quot;);
                            newSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
                            if (newSocket.getKeepAlive()) {
                                LOGGER.info(&quot;Server socket keep alive to host (&quot; + host + &quot;,&quot; + port + &quot;) for BankID:&quot; + Integer.toString(this.getBankID()));
                            }                                   
                            activeSocket.setSocket(newSocket);
                            activeSockets.add(activeSocket);
                            increaseConnects();
                            break;
                        } catch (final SocketException ex) {
                            LOGGER.info(&quot;SocketException while opening socket.&quot;);
                            LOGGER.warn(FormatData.fullStackTrace(ex));
                            newSocket = null;
                        }
                    }
                } else { // first time through the loop
                    try {
                        LOGGER.info(&quot;Opening server socket (&quot; + host + &quot;,&quot; + port + &quot;) for BankID:&quot; + Integer.toString(this.getBankID()));
                        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                    } catch (final IOException ex) {
                        LOGGER.info(&quot;Unable to open server socket socket (&quot; + host + &quot;,&quot; + port + &quot;)&quot;);
                        if (ex.getMessage().indexOf(&quot;Cannot assign requested address&quot;) &gt; -1) {
                            this.terminate();
                            final String logMessage = &quot;Invalid IP Address assigned:&quot; + host + &quot;,port:&quot; + port;
                            final String subject = logMessage;
                            ATMServer.sendNotification(subject, logMessage);
                        } else if (tries == 0) {
                            tries++;
                            final String logMessage = &quot;Unable to open server socket (&quot; + host + &quot;,&quot; + port + &quot;)&quot;;
                            final String subject = &quot;Unable to open server socket (&quot; + host + &quot;,&quot; + port + &quot;)&quot;;
                            ATMServer.sendNotification(subject, logMessage);
                        }
                        LOGGER.warn(FormatData.fullStackTrace(ex));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else { // client socket -- connecting to entity

        clientSocket = true;
        while (!shouldTerminate && (activeSockets.size() &lt; this.maxActiveSockets)) {
            activeSocket = new ActiveSocket(this);
            newSocket = null;
            if (this.isInForcedStandIn()) {
                LOGGER.info(&quot;Forced standin &quot; + getName());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000); 
                } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
                    LOGGER.info(&quot;Interrupted while waiting for connection.&quot;);
                    LOGGER.warn(FormatData.fullStackTrace(ex));
                }
            } else {
                if (!shouldTerminate) {
                    if ((loopCounter % 120) == 0) {
                        try {
                            LOGGER.info(&quot;Connecting to host (&quot; + remoteHost + &quot;,&quot; + remotePort + &quot;) for BankID:&quot; + Integer.toString(this.getBankID()));
                            newSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(remoteHost), remotePort);
                            if (newSocket.isConnected()) {
                                tries = 0;
                                LOGGER.info(&quot;Client socket connected to host (&quot; + remoteHost + &quot;,&quot; + remotePort + &quot;) for BankID:&quot; + Integer.toString(this.getBankID()));
                            }
                            newSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
                            if (newSocket.getKeepAlive()) {
                                LOGGER.info(&quot;Client socket keep alive to host (&quot; + remoteHost + &quot;,&quot; + remotePort + &quot;) for BankID:&quot; + Integer.toString(this.getBankID()));
                            }
                            activeSocket.setSocket(newSocket);
                            activeSockets.add(activeSocket);
                            increaseConnects();
                            break;
                        } catch (final IOException ex) {
                            loopCounter++;
                            tries++;
                            LOGGER.info(&quot;SocketException while opening remote socket (&quot; + remoteHost + &quot;,&quot; + remotePort + &quot;) &quot; + &quot; &quot; + ex.getClass() + &quot; &quot; + ex.getMessage());

                            if ((tries % 300) == 0) {
                                recordErrorToDatabase(ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        loopCounter++;
                        try {
                            synchronized (clientConnectLock) {
                                clientConnectLock.wait(1000);
                            }
                        } catch (final InterruptedException inex) {
                            LOGGER.info(&quot;SocketException while opening remote socket &quot; + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            LOGGER.warn(FormatData.fullStackTrace(inex));
                            if (!this.shouldTerminate) {
                                recordErrorToDatabase(&quot;InterruptedException without terminate set.&quot;);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    try {
        // here, if we created a new ActiveSocket, establish dataInput and dataOuput streams
        // for Discover, this will mean adding up to MaxActiveSockets # of sockets to the activeSockets list.
        // for each other SwitchChannel, this will be the only activeSocket
        if (activeSocket != null) {
            LOGGER.info(&quot;Creating serverIn/serverOut data streams &quot; + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(newSocket.getInputStream()));
            if (newSocket.isConnected()) {
                LOGGER.info(&quot;socket still connected to host (&quot; + remoteHost + &quot;,&quot; + remotePort + &quot;) for BankID:&quot; + Integer.toString(this.getBankID()));
            }
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(newSocket.getOutputStream(), 2048));
            activeSocket.setDataInputStream(dataInputStream);
            activeSocket.setDataOutputStream(dataOutputStream);                 
            //activeSockets.add(activeSocket);
            activeSocket.setNumReceivers(this.numReceivers);
            ReceiveQueuer[] receiveQueuers = activeSocket.getReceiveQueuers();
            LOGGER.info(&quot;Starting receive queuers&quot;);
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt &lt; numReceivers; cnt++) {
                receiveQueuers[cnt].setName(this.systemName + &quot;-Socket-&quot; + Integer.toString(activeSockets.size()) + &quot;-ReceiveQueuer-&quot; + Integer.toString(cnt));
                receiveQueuers[cnt].setActiveSocket(activeSocket);
                receiveQueuers[cnt].start();
            }
        }
        if (clientSocket) {
            break;
        }
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.info(&quot;Exception while creating input/output streams &quot; + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        LOGGER.warn(FormatData.fullStackTrace(ex));
    }
}
if (!shouldTerminate) {
    LOGGER.info(&quot;Socket connection complete &quot; + Thread.currentThread().getName());
} else {
    LOGGER.info(&quot;Stopped establishing socket connection &quot; + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

}

Comment: The basic idea when going multi-socket is to have one thread whose only responsibility is to accept sockets, then spawn of "handler" threads to deal with the different connections (injecting the newly accepted sockets to them). I am afraid that will need major refactoring here.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use multiple sockets is to allocate a new thread don't try to use different sockets on one thread you'll make it very hard for yourself